# How do non-HTML5 JavaScript HSV color pickers work?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain how JavaScript color pickers work? (The ones that don't use HTML5 canvas.)

My first idea was to generate (thousands of) 1px divs programmatic ally and give them a slightly different background color. But I think there has to be a better solution than this!

Comment: Why vote for close? I think this is a question that can be very well answered and not just discussed.

Comment: Hmm, I really wonder why there are votes for "not constructive"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a standard picker, you need a static image with an alpha gradient from left (opaque) to right (transparent), and a color gradient from top (white) to bottom (black). Create a DIV, and the image in it.

The Hue picker is a static image. When a hue is selected, the background color of the DIV changes to this hue. The transparent image on top of the DIV will alter this underlying color, and simulate a proper color picker. Magic isn't it ?

**Edit:** This is an HSV picker, the hue picker selects, well, the Hue. The X coordinate on the big picker is the Saturation, and the Y is the Brightness (or value). You will then probably need an HSV to RGB algorithm.

Comment: Both semi-transparent overlays and the hue bar could be also [CSS3 gradients](http://codepo8.github.com/CSS3-Rainbow-Dividers/).

Comment: Sounds good. :) But can you explain how I find out what color the user  picked?

Comment: Damn, it's even niftyer with gradients !

Comment: Edited answer with how to find out what color the user picked.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a colour picker, there are several examples available via jQuery. Look at: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ for example. I've used that particular one before.

Comment: I'd like to code my own one for fun. ;) So I'm not interested in these finsihed ones. If I need something like that, I'm just going to google it.

Comment: ...but this is better suited as a comment. Summarize up the behavior and/or add an excerpt from the appropriate reference to make this answer more useful in context.

Comment: I'm new to SO so I'll take that on board.