# How do non-HTML5 JavaScript RGB color pickers work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371115/how-do-non-html5-javascript-hsv-color-pickers-work) how HSV color pickers work, now I would like to know how RGB color pickers with JavaScript work. Those that don't use the HTML5 Canvas API. Could somebody explain me the concept behind them?

Here is an example of what I mean: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

*Note: I'm not looking for ready to use jQuery color pickers. I want to develop my own one for learning purposes! jQuery for the solution is fine though!*

Comment: What about them don't you understand?

Comment: There are lots of ways to implement color pickers in javascript.  Can you link to an example that you'd like explained?

Comment: oh -- and bravo for wanting to learn!

Comment: @ajax81 I added an example, see above!

Comment: @Bakudan-ханювиги Your solution needs help from the server. I favour a way of doing all of it on the client, it is possible, see jQuery UI or the example I linked at my question. Thanks though!

Comment: This is all right and well, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Pekka Simple: I want to know how those color pickers work. E.g.: How is this color field on the left (look at the example I gave) generated? How can I find out what color has been picked? Does that answer your question?

Comment: So basically, you want to learn by having it written out for you? I'm confused. :) Do you just need to learn how to backtrace code and find out how things work?

Comment: I feel the need to note that color pickers have been around a lot longer than HTML5 and jQuery.

Comment: @MetalFrog Read my question more carefully. I'm asking for the concept. I want to write all of the code myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to pick RGB values between 0 and 255, similar to the example you are linking to, here's how I would approach it:

- Generate 1 static image (1x256 pixels) that contains the 'rainbow gradient' shown in the slider on the right
- Generate 1 static overlay image RGBA image of 256x256 pixels as follows

  - top left: R=1 G=1 B=1 A=1
  - top right: R=0 G=0 B=0 A=0
  - bottom left: R=0 G=0 B=0 A=1
  - bottom right: R=0 G=0 B=0 A=1
- Use the first image as a background for the slider. It should generate the color to be displayed in the top left corner of the color picker. Use mouse coordinates to find the actual Y value for the color
- create a 'background' div (256x256 px) that has the color picked with the slider. Use the second static image as on overlay div on top of it. With the alpha values it should give you a white and 2 black corners and one corner of the color you need.
- use the mouse coordinates in that that square. The color will have to be calculated.

I'm leaving creating the formulas and images to you. :)